# How do I log into a Stack Exchange site with my openid? 

Tags: support, openid, login

I'd like to log into this site with my open id, just username and password same as I've got into many Stack Exchange sites, but I see no option for it, it seems to want an email address. Is there a way to just log in with openid username and password as I have with others?

https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/login

Comment: Click where it says "Show more login options" right below the 4 main buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on "Show more login options" to show the openID address entry box, or select any other openID provider.

[image]

[image]